# Is there some documentation on which character sets are definitely supported by Android version?

Tags: fonts

There is a lot of vague information such as ["Android supports RTL since 4.1.1"](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages), from which I abduce that Android natively supports (some) Arabic, Hebrew, Persian and Urdu characters. Likewise some question on Stack Overflow such as [What glyphs or character sets are included in Roboto fonts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150547/what-glyphs-or-character-sets-are-included-in-roboto-fonts), which is not definitely answered.

There are many scripts which are obscure by Silicon Valley standard but used by millions of people, such as [Syriac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syriac_language) or [Amharic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amharic). I have noticed that new versions of Android display Syriac (since Oreo?), and further back (JellyBean?) support Amharic.

But I find it very difficult to just find a plain list of supported alphabets per Android version. Is it different per manufacturer, or does Google require every Android distribution to support at least a certain character set?

If I download an app with Amharic translations targeting API versions > JellyBean (for instance) should the developer include a font in the APK to be sure that I won't see tofus?